# Как проверить localStorage и заполнить input-ы?

Tags: javascript

Есть форма регистрации. Поля Name, E-mail, Date of Birth сохраняются в localStorage.

Как правильно прописать функцию, которая проверяет, есть ли заданные значения у соответствующих ключей в localStorage, и если есть, складывает значения в соответствующие поля при перезагрузке страницы?

Для одного поля понятно, как это сделать. А для трех не совсем. Прописывать кучу IF не хочется.

```
window.onload = function () {

    //Set localStorage

    var userName = document.getElementById("nameField");
    var userEmail = document.getElementById("emailField");
    var userDateOfBirth = document.getElementById("dateField");


    //Wnen out of focus - set localStorage

    userName.addEventListener("focusout", (event) => {
        localStorage.setItem("userName", userName.value);
    });

     userEmail.addEventListener("focusout", (event) => {
         localStorage.setItem("userEmail", userEmail.value);
     });

      userDateOfBirth.addEventListener("focusout", (event) => {
          localStorage.setItem("userDateOfBirth", userDateOfBirth.value);
      });

    //Get localStorage

    var userNameStorage = localStorage.getItem("userName");
    var userEmailStorage = localStorage.getItem("userEmail");
    var userDateOfBirthStorage = localStorage.getItem("userDateOfBirth");

    function getLocalStorage() {

    }

    getLocalStorage();

};
```

[JS FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/Nikita_Migushev/nmwsvj4y/2/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
//Set localStorage

const userName = document.getElementById("nameField");
const userEmail = document.getElementById("emailField");
const userDateOfBirth = document.getElementById("dateField");


//Wnen out of focus - set localStorage

userName.addEventListener("focusout", (event) => {
  localStorage.setItem(event.target.id, userName.value);
});

userEmail.addEventListener("focusout", (event) => {
  localStorage.setItem(event.target.id, userEmail.value);
});

userDateOfBirth.addEventListener("focusout", (event) => {
  localStorage.setItem(event.target.id, userDateOfBirth.value);
});

//Get localStorage

function getLocalStorage() {
  const inputs = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('input'));

  inputs.map(input => {
    const val = localStorage.getItem(input.id);
    return val ? input.value = val : input.value = '';
  })
}

getLocalStorage();
```

```html
<section class="contactForm">
  <h1>Create account</h1>
  <form id="registration-form" action="php/register.php" method="POST">
    <p>
      <label>Your name</label>
      <input required type="text" name="name" value="" id="nameField">

    </p>
    <p>
      <label>Email</label>
      <input required type="email" name="email" value="" id="emailField">


    </p>
    <p>
      <label>Date of birth</label>
      <input required type="text" name="date" value="" id="dateField" class="datePicker">

    </p>
    <p>
      <label>Password</label>
      <input required type="password" name="password" value="" id="passwordField">

    </p>
    <p>
      <label>Re-enter Password</label>
      <input required type="password" name="re-password" value="" id="re-passwordField">

    </p>
    <p>
      <button class="full submitButton" type="submit">Create your account</button>
    </p>
  </form>

</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

Проще и удобнее - примерно так:

```
const frm = document.querySelector('#registration-form'); 

// чтение
let state = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('regForm') || '{}'); 
Object.keys(state).forEach(name => {
  const inp = frm.querySelector(`[name="${name}"]`); 
  if (inp) inp.value = state[name]; 
}); 

/* ... */

// запись 
state = [...frm.querySelectorAll('input[name]')].reduce(
  (r, { name, value }) => Object.assign(r, { [name]: value })
, {}); 
localStorage.setItem('regForm', JSON.stringify(state));
```

Фильтрацию элементов (исходя из их `name`, `type`, или других атрибутов) - добавить по вкусу.

Comment: Спасибо. Интересный подход